# Group by week day in .NET 6 and EF Core 6

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have an invoice table that I want to perform a weekly analysis on operations based on days of the week. The following SQL query is executed correctly.

```
select DATENAME(weekday, [InvoiceDate]) as Day, sum([TotalPrice]) as PurchaseAmount, count(*) as VisitCount
from [Invoices]
group by DATENAME(weekday, [InvoiceDate]);
```

Expected result:

[image: Expected result.]

Unfortunately, the following code does not work in .NET 6 and EF Core; return null or exception.

```
var results = _db.Invoices.GroupBy(i => new { i.InvoiceDate.DayOfWeek}).Select(x =>
            new DailyStatistics
            {
                Day = x.Key.ToString(),
                PurchaseAmount = x.Sum(s => s.TotalPrice),
                VisitCount = x.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please show the exception (type + full message).

Comment: Maybe you have records with an `InvoiceDate` which is `null`. If that's a `DateTime?` you need to change the `GroupBy`-condition, so add a `NoInvoice`.

Comment: You need to cast the dayofweek to an integer : (int)i.InvoiceDate.DayOfWeek

Comment: SQL translation of `DayOfWeek` is not supported. A work-around (if it doesn't pull a large amount of data) is to get the data in a `Select` statement including `DayOfWeek` and do the grouping on the in-memory data. EF will execute `DayOfWeek` client-side if it's in the final `Select`.

Comment: you can call the stored procedure from C# code